# Write spark dataframe to postgres table with defined column constrains in db table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark df which needs to be saved in the postgres table. I want to create the table in the db if it doesn't exist and define the column constraints in the database column, like making one column Primary, one unique and rest keep them as nullable.

I want the table to be of columns
`"uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE, address TEXT, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, geometry GEOMETRY(Point, 4326), timestamp TIMESTAMP, json JSONB"`

My dataframe's schema is:

```
root
 |-- uuid: string (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- geometry: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- json: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm using pyspark-3.3.1

I'm able to create the table and append but not with the desired datatype and constraints

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("df_psql") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", database_url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("driver", properties["driver"]) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

but when I tried adding `createTableColumnTypes` I am unable to add the column constraints or the datatype

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have the datatypes as a list, let's say -

```
column_types = {
    "uuid": "UUID PRIMARY KEY",
    "name": "TEXT UNIQUE",
    "address": "TEXT",
    "latitude": "DOUBLE",
    "longitude": "DOUBLE",
    "geometry": "GEOMETRY(Point, 4326)",
    "timestamp": "TIMESTAMP",
    "json": "JSONB"
}
```

and change it into a comma seperated string to have it parsed through the df.write function.

```
create_table_column_types = ", ".join([f"{col} {data_type}" for col, data_type in column_types.items()])
```

after which, you can save the dataframe by passing this variable onto the createTableColumnTypes, something like this -

```
df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", database_url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("driver", properties["driver"]) \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", create_table_column_types) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

That's one possibility to get your query sorted.

Comment: It still gives the same error

```Syntax error at or near 'PRIMARY'(line 1, pos 10)

== SQL ==
uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE, address TEXT, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, geometry GEOMETRY(Point, 4326), timestamp TIMESTAMP, json JSONB
----------^^^
```

Comment: How about making a custom query to execute first that creates the table and then the usuals? 
```
columns_str = ", ".join([f"{col} {data_type}" for col, data_type in column_types.items()])

custom_query = f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
        {columns_str},
        PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
        CONSTRAINT {table_name}_name_unique UNIQUE (name)
    )
"""

df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", database_url) \
    .option("driver", properties["driver"]) \
    .option("dbtable", f"({custom_query}) as tmp") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```